# How to use jaas configuration in spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I followed this [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas) to create an authentication in my broker kafka, however there are two differences for my project

1. I use kafka streams binder, while in the example kafka binder is
   used.
2. I only have one broker, while in the example two brokers are
   used.

When I run my application it returns the following error:

https://gist.github.com/JacsonF/7363e8d7f4f07a5bc77c28fb1e882674

My function:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<Object, String>, KStream<?, String>[]> receive() {
    Predicate<Object, String> isCompensado = (k, v) -> v.contains("XPTO");
    Predicate<Object, String> isntCompensado = (k, v) -> !v.contains("XPTO");
    return input -> input.branch(isCompensado, isntCompensado);
}
```

**I would like to use only the properties of my application to authenticate, without an external file, just like in the example.
How can I do this?**

[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GftXS.png)

Comment: Can you give more from your stacktrace? We need to see the caused by from the trace to see what the root cause of the issues you are running into.

Comment: thanks for replying, i updated and uploaded the full log to make it  understand

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper setup for `KafkaClient` in your config file? See this README for how to set up the Kakfa environment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas/README.adoc

Comment: Specifically, you need the `Client` info in your config file.

Comment: @sobychacko I'm create [this](https://github.com/JacsonF/streams-kafka-binder-jaas-sample)  implementation, I don't know if the best approach, if you check and  respond me it would be great.  Maybe I wasn't clear in reporting the  problem, I tried to explain it better in the project I submitted

Comment: Hi, I will try to see if I can reproduce the error that you got in the first place. Is the project you shared working for you? I guess you can use that as a workaround if it works. But, I will try to see if there is anything missing on the framework side.

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue with the way JAAS configuration was processed in Kafka Streams binder for Spring Cloud Stream. See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1092) for more details. This is fixed now. Make sure that you are using version `3.1.4-SNAPSHOT`. Here is a [sample application](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-jaas-security) that verifies this.

**Update**

The Kafka binders for Spring Cloud Stream have been released, version 3.1.4 has the fix.

If you're using `spring-cloud-dependencies` in your pom to manage dependencies, update it to (at least) version 2020.0.4
For example:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: That's great! it work's fine for me, thank you very much.

Comment: @JacsonF you should accept this answer, the new version of SpCS Kafka Binder does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

`spring.kafka.jaas.enabled=true`

`spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL`

`spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN`

`spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="username" password="password";`

Output:

```
2021-05-18 18:50:56.505  INFO 75288 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Creating binder: ktable
2021-05-18 18:50:56.595  INFO 75288 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Caching the binder: ktable
2021-05-18 18:50:56.596  INFO 75288 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: ktable
2021-05-18 18:50:56.722  INFO 75288 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
    ............ (property)=(value) ............
    sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    ............ (property)=(value) ............
2021-05-18 18:50:56.960  INFO 75288 --- [           main] o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.
2021-05-18 18:50:57.131  WARN 75288 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : The configuration 'sasl.jaas.config' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-05-18 18:50:57.134  INFO 75288 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.6.0
2021-05-18 12:46:31.423  INFO 74020 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
2021-05-18 12:46:31.423  INFO 74020 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1621367191408
2021-05-18 12:46:31.423  INFO 74020 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Auto creation of topics is disabled.
2021-05-18 12:46:31.456  INFO 74020 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig   : StreamsConfig values:
```

I tried the following but not working for me:

- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka#using-spring-boot-properties

Using the properties from the above link to set the same values as the first way will have the following error:

```
2021-05-18 18:59:44.140  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Creating binder: ktable
2021-05-18 18:59:44.231  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Caching the binder: ktable
2021-05-18 18:59:44.232  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: ktable
2021-05-18 18:59:44.352  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values:
    ............ (property)=(value) .............
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ............ (property)=(value) ............
2021-05-18 18:59:44.596  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.6.0
2021-05-18 18:59:44.597  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
2021-05-18 18:59:44.597  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1621389584594
2021-05-18 18:59:44.599  INFO 73444 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Auto creation of topics is disabled.
2021-05-18 18:59:44.611  INFO 73444 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1621389614599, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.
```

From the logging, you can see that the second way is NOT using the values you provided and there is no "Successfully logged in".

By the way, I am using the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the following repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```